# How do different encryption schemes scale as a relation between their security parameter and computational requirement?

Tags: rsa, aes

For example is it harder to break one 256 bit encryption than two 255 bit encryption for RSA and AES?

For example, I understand that 256 bit RSA can be cracked in one minute according to this article [1] So would two independent 255 bit RSA message take thirty seconds each, and four 254 bit messages take 15 seconds each, etc... or would two 255 bit messages take 1 minute total on average?

[1] https://www.doyler.net/security-not-included/cracking-256-bit-rsa-keys

Comment: As a starting point, why not just take a look at https://keylength.com, it links to the various methods that are used to calculate key strength. As for your (homework?) question, have you heard about meet-in-the-middle?

Comment: Haha, not a homework question. 

I was just wondering if their key space is additive or if other interaction is at play. To clarify these are two different 255 bit encryption, not one message that has been encrypted twice. 

Thanks, I will look into meet-in-the-middle.

Comment: Could you please clarify your scheme in the question by hitting [edit]? 255 bit RSA is not secure.

Comment: Will do. Sorry if the question is not clear. I understand that 256 bit RSA can be cracked in one minute according to this article [1] My question is about the rate of change as it relates to increasing the key length. So would two independent 255 bit RSA message take thirty seconds each, and four 254 bit messages take 15 seconds each, etc...

[1] https://www.doyler.net/security-not-included/cracking-256-bit-rsa-keys

Comment: RSA and AES need to be used in a mode of operation to operate as a secure cipher. You cannot just say use RSA-255 twice with two different keys either. For one, usually the plaintext size needs to be significantly smaller for RSA to be secure, so the ciphertext of one RSA operation will likely not fit into another. Symmetric ciphers operate entirely differently from asymmetric ciphers, and may be vulnerable against meet-in-the-middle attacks as mentioned earlier. In other words, both the Q and the A may be more complex than you might imagine.

Comment: Understood. I see that I require a more fundamental understanding of both schemes to ask the right question. I also found this wiki page [1] which kinda points me towards the right direction. Thanks for your help [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers Thanks